# Программа, считывающая стоп-слова и строку-запрос

Tags: c++, vector, set

Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать этот код для условия:
Первая строка ввода содержит стоп-слова, разделённые пробелом. Вторая строка содержит поисковый запрос.
Программа должна вывести слова поискового запроса, которых нет среди стоп-слов. Каждое слово, прошедшее проверку, выводится в отдельной строке внутри символов [ и ]. Слова должны выводиться в том же порядке, в каком они были в строке запроса.
Разбейте строку стоп-слов на отдельные слова и сделайте из них множество. Вектор слов строки запроса надо формировать, предварительно проверяя, содержится ли очередное слово внутри множества стоп-слов. Для этого используйте метод count.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector<string> SplitIntoWords(string text) {
vector<string> words;
string word;
for (const char c : text) {
if (c == ' ') {
if (!word.empty()) {
words.push_back(word);
word.clear();
}
} else {
word += c;
}
}
if (!word.empty()) {
words.push_back(word);
}

return words;
}


int main() {
/* Считайте строку со стоп-словами */

// Считываем строку-запрос
string query;
getline(cin, query);

// Выведите только те слова, которых нет среди стоп-слов
for (string word : SplitIntoWords(query)) {
cout << '[' << word << ']' << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно почему Вы не делали ввод стоп слов, их тоже можно сохранить в вектор, после чего написать функцию поиска по вектору используя `find` из `algorithm`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<string> SplitIntoWords(string text) {
  vector<string> words;
  string word;
  for (const char c : text) {
    if (c == ' ') {
      if (!word.empty()) {
        words.push_back(word);
        word.clear();
      }
    } else {
      word += c;
    }
  }
  if (!word.empty()) {
    words.push_back(word);
  }
  return words;
}

bool contains (vector<string> v, string word) {
    return (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), word) != v.end());
}

int main() {
  /* Считайте строку со стоп-словами */
  string stopWordsLine;
  getline(cin, stopWordsLine);
  vector<string> stopWords = SplitIntoWords(stopWordsLine);         
  // Считываем строку-запрос
  string query;
  getline(cin, query);
  // Выведите только те слова, которых нет среди стоп-слов
  
  for (string word : SplitIntoWords(query)) {
    if (!contains(stopWords, word))
        cout << '[' << word << ']' << endl;
  }
}
```